# Speed up and simplify

Tags: excel, vba

I cobbled together something that does work for me as is, but it runs very slowly and I'm sure the code can be simplified.

```
Sub CopyPasteValues()

Dim strSht1, strSht2 As String
Dim c, rng As Range

strSht1 = "Edit"
strSht2 = "LOB"


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSht1)
Set rng = Range("J2:AJ37")

    For Each c In rng
       If Not c.Value = 0 Then
       Cells(c.Row, 2).Copy
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSht2).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Range(Cells(c.Row, 4), Cells(c.Row, 5)).Copy
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSht2).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       c.Copy
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSht2).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Cells(c.Column).Copy
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSht2).Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
     Next c
End With
End Sub
```

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Read the entire range into a `Variant` array first, then loop the array.

Comment: Some standard... `application.screenupdating = false`, `application.enableevents = false`, ensure you're only calculating as necessary.  You use `rows.count` without qualifications, and if you are pasting to the same row for each, you could calculate that once as a variable and define your columns as necessary.  If you don't care about formatting, use `destination.value = source.value` rather than copy-pasting.  The list goes on.  Side note, CodeReview is the StackExchange site for these types of requests.

Comment: When making a large number of sheet changes, its a good idea to set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` until you're done making sheet changes, and then set it back to `xlCalculationAutomatic`. But this is a Band-Aid solution. The best solution is what @BigBen suggested, take the values into an array, build an array containing your output values, and then paste it all onto the sheet in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BigBen Mentioned, array method.
Super Fast.

```
Sub Move_Values_Array_Method()

    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet        'Source Worksheet
    Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet   'Destination Worksheet
    Dim RG As Range                     'Source Range
    Dim InArr()                         'Data In Array
    Dim OutArr()                        'Data Out Array
    Dim X As Long                       'Array X Position for purposes of iterating through array.
    Dim Y As Long                       'Array Y Position for purposes of iterating through array.
    Dim Cnt As Long                     'Found Value Count
    
    Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Edit")       'Set Source Worksheet
    Set DestinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LOB")   'Set Dest Worksheet
    Set RG = SourceSheet.Range("J2:AJ37")                   'Set Source Range
    ReDim OutArr(1 To RG.Cells.Count)                       'Count Cells in Range, resize output array to be at least that big.
    InArr = RG                                              'Transfer Range Data to Array
    Cnt = 0
    
    Debug.Print LBound(InArr, 1) & " - " & UBound(InArr, 1) 'Rows
    Debug.Print LBound(InArr, 2) & " - " & UBound(InArr, 2) 'Columns
    
    For Y = 1 To UBound(InArr, 1)           'For Each Row in Array (or each Y position)
        For X = 1 To UBound(InArr, 2)       'For Each Column in Array (or each X position)
            If InArr(Y, X) <> "" Then       'If not blank Value (you can change this to "If InArr(Y, X) <> 0 Then" if that works best for you.
                Cnt = Cnt + 1               'Increment "found value count" by 1
                OutArr(Cnt) = InArr(Y, X)   'Add found value to output array
            End If
        Next X
    Next Y
    
    'Output to Dest Sheet
    DestinationSheet.Range("F2").Resize(UBound(OutArr, 1), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(OutArr())
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I should give a bit more info into the function I am trying to accomplish.  The intent is to have the macro run through the columns until it finds a cell with a value greater than zero.  Upon finding each instance, It should copy that value (Qty.), the column header (Date), as well as the text in B (Customer), D (Part#), and E (Description) of that row.  Ultimately, this is just to sort a purchasing forecast.

Comment: Cameron's coding seems great, but I'm not sure I understand how to adjust it to fit my needs appropriately...?

Comment: Ah Okay, so what I'm getting is you need to only check one column for whether data>0, then , if so, copy specific data from that row to a new sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in your previous comments, try these alternative solution using formulas and filters...

**1) Array Formulas**

*To note:*

- *I have put everything on one sheet for clarity, but it works just as well over multiple sheets, or even workbooks.*
- *If you want to filter the entire sheet, with same column order, you only need to enter formula once and expand "Array" criteria in formula to encapsulate entire data set.*

> Formula used in cell "J4" = "=FILTER($I$4:$I$30,$C$4:$C$30>0)"
> *(filter range I4 to I30 to show rows where value in range C4 to C30 is greater than 0)*

[image: Example of filter formula]

**2) Directly Filter**

Alternatively, you could (either manually or programmatically) copy all data to LOB sheet, (or selectively copy), then filter for Qty>0.